# Incompatibility between TornadoFX and lowagie iText

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, itext, tornadofx

I have a desktop application developed with TornadoFX (jaxaFx + kotlin) and when I insert the lowagie iText library in the dependencies declaration, the application stops working. When I compile with the iText library, the application just doesn't run. It doesn't return any error messages and doesn't even enter Main. Has anyone had a similar problem?

> dependencies {
> implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.3.72")
> implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.72")
> implementation("no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.20")
> implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed:0.10.4")
> implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18")
> implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.26")
> implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
> implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3")
> implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5")
> implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.5")
> implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-javafx:1.3.5")
> implementation("net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1")
>
> implementation("com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7")
>
> implementation files("libs/OpenCV${opencv_version}/opencv-${opencv_version}.jar", "libs/RXTXcomm/RXTXcomm.jar")
> runtimeOnly files("libs/OpenCV${opencv_version}/x64/opencv_java${opencv_version}.dll", >"libs/RXTXcomm/rxtxSerial.dll")
> }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. Was "Invalid signature file". I put this command in gradle file and the problem was solved

> exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'